# How does Cisco from Flash know the unknown?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Okay so guys, all of the meta-humans on The Flash have been caused by the particle accelerator, right. They got their powers and all of them can be proved, or stopped by physics. But Cisco, how does he know stuff that no one else knows? For example S02e02 he touched the sand from sand-demon and then he found out where he was keeping Patty hostage. I mean what scientific explanation is there for that?

Comment: You're asking for a scientific explanation for superpowers?!

Comment: "The Speed Force".

Answer (score 4):

He too got exposed to the blast of the particle accelerator. People who got hit got a variety of superpowers: one got the powers of a tar monster, one got deadly gas powers, another got weather powers, Barry got the power of goes fast and Cisco got the ability to vibe.

In short: It's comic book science. It's not intended to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

He also was a metahuman, but for some reason his ability took a while to manifest, no one (including Cisco himself) realized it until after Barry changed the past for the first time and Cisco remembered Thawne killing him in the timeline that Barry prevented.